# How to use scanf() to capture only Strings

Tags: c, arrays, char, scanf

Hi i am new to C and i am trying to use the Character array type below to captures input from users. How do i prevent or escape numerical characters. I just want only strings to be captured.

```
char str_input[105];
```

In have tried

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",str_input);
scanf("%[^\n]",str_input);
scanf("%[^0-9]",str_input);
scanf("%[A-Zaz-z]",str_input);
str_input = fgetc(stdin);
```

None of the above worked for me.

**Input**

> 2
>
> hacker

**Expected Output**

> Hce akr

```
int main() {
    char *str_input;
    size_t bufsize = 108;
    size_t characters;

    str_input = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if (str_input == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
        exit(1);
    }

    characters = getline(&str_input,&bufsize,stdin);
    printf("%zu characters were read.\n",characters);
    int i;
    int len = 0;

    for (i = 0, len = strlen(str_input); i<=len; i++) {
        i%2==0? printf("%c",str_input[i]): 'b'; 
    }
    printf(" ");

    for (i = 0, len = strlen(str_input); i<=len; i++) {
        i%2!=0? printf("%c",str_input[i]): 'b'; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error

```
solution.c: In function ‘main’:
solution.c:21:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getline’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     characters = getline(&str_input,&bufsize,stdin);
```

Comment: Using a `-` to denote a range of characters is an implementation defined feature.

Comment: Normally you first get the input and then scan it. `fgetc` gets a single character but it seems you want a string. I further understand you want to reject input with numbers. That means to tell the user something like `Wrong input. Please re-enter`, which menas a loop until you got the right input.

Comment: Read the whole line (with `fgets`) then manually loop over the string to make sure it's only [letters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) (and possibly [spaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace))?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes, i tried a loop but didn't work. I even tried while(isalpha(str_input)){...............} it didn't work

Comment: Hint: use strspn() to find the length of the initial substring with only characters belonging to a certain set.

Comment: [The `getline` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) is a good reference. Note which header file it tells you to use.

Comment: If your using a limited size buffer, why not just use `fgets()`?

Comment: @RoadRunner Can you give me an example please

Comment: @RoadRunner, in fgets() the parameter is supposed to be a fileStream, i am not using a file stream

Comment: @ARTHURDECKER `stdin` is also a stream. `fgets(str_input, INPUTSIZE, stdin)` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Okay thanks @RoadRunner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your buffer has limited size, then using [`fgets(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) is fine. `fgets()` returns `NULL` on failure to read a line, and appends a newline character at the end of the buffer.

In terms of preventing numerical characters from being in your buffer, you can simply create another buffer, and only add non-numerical characters to it. You could just delete the numerical characters from your original buffer, but this can be a tedious procedure if you are still grasping the basics of C. Another method would be just to read single character input with [`getchar(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar), which would allow you assess each character and simply ignore numbers. THis method is by far the easiest to implement.

Since you asked for an example of using `fgets()`, here is some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define INPUTSIZE 108

int main(void) {
    char str_input[INPUTSIZE], characters[INPUTSIZE];
    size_t slen, char_count = 0;

    printf("Enter input:\n");
    if (fgets(str_input, INPUTSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {

        /* removing newline from fgets() */
        slen = strlen(str_input);
        if (slen > 0 && str_input[slen-1] == '\n') {
            str_input[slen-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Number of characters entered exceeds buffer size\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* checking if string is valid */
        if (*str_input == '\0') {
            fprintf(stderr, "No input found\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("Buffer: %s\n", str_input);

        /* only adding non-numbers */
        for (size_t i = 0; str_input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (!isdigit(str_input[i])) {
                characters[char_count++] = str_input[i];
            }
        }

        /* terminating buffer */
        characters[char_count] = '\0';

        printf("New buffer without numbers: %s\n", characters);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example input:

```
Enter input:
2ttt4y24t4t3t2g
```

Output:

```
Buffer: 2ttt4y24t4t3t2g
New buffer without numbers: tttytttg
```

**Update:**

You could just use this even simpler approach of ignoring non-number characters:

```
char str_input[INPUTSIZE];
int ch;
size_t char_count = 0;

while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
    if (!isdigit(ch)) {
        if (char_count < sizeof(str_input)) {
            str_input[char_count++] = ch;
        }
    }
} 

str_input[char_count] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Linux, I would use the getline() function to get a whole line of text, then verify it. If it is not valid input, I would in a loop ask the user to enter a line of text again and again until you the input is acceptable.

If not using Linux, well, your best bet is probably to reimplement getline(). You can also use fgets() if you find a limited-size buffer acceptable. I don't find limited-size buffers acceptable, so that's why I prefer getline().

getline() is used according to the way explained in its man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html

Basically, your loop should be something similar to:

```
char *buf = NULL;
size_t bufsiz = 0;
while (1)
{
    if (getline(&buf, &bufsiz, stdin) < 0)
    {
        handle_error();
    }
    if (is_valid(buf))
    {
        break;
    }
    printf("Error, please re-enter input\n");
}
use_buffer(buf);
free(buf);
```

Comment: getline() does not escape numerical values

Comment: @ARTHURDECKER That would be part of "If it is not valid input..."

Answer (score 1):

Well that's not possible. Numbers are string too. But you can set loop to look for numbers and print error. like this :

```
 char *str = "ab234cid20kd", *p = str;
while (*p) { // While there are more characters to process...
    if (isdigit(*p)) { // Upon finding a digit, ...
        printf("Numbers are forbidden");
        return 0;
    } else {
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Poor string literal, doesn't even get the honour of being `const`.